# Distinguishing Road Network according to the ward within a municipality ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, network, zonal-statistics, road

I have a polygon layer of a municipality containing 14 wards as shown in figure i.
I also have a polyline layer of road network irrespective of the ward.

[image: Figure i - Municipality map showing wards and road network]

The road network have following attributes - Road digital name, Road length, Road class, road width, road name as shown in figure ii.
[image: Figure ii - Road polyline attribute table]

I want to distinguish each road polyline according to 14 wards such that I could generate summary about each ward having so-and-so roads, with so-and-so length of roads. (Segments of one roads may lie on more than one ward). I want to generate Zonal Statistics but both of the layer is feature layer (as different from zonal stat tools in arcgis where one layer must be raster).

In summary, I would like to categorized each segment of the road (and not the single road network) for each ward.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to specify the version of ArcGIS in use and the license level (Basic, Standard, Advanced). This is a basic application of an [overlay operation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/commonly-used-tools/overlay-analysis.htm#GUID-D0A746B7-3AAB-4A4D-B7AF-AEE68D0B5C9D). Have you tried combining an Intersect with summary statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do with an "Intersection" of the Roads with the Wards. Intersection will give you back a polyline road layer will all the fields of both layers (so you will be able to summarize by Ward).

Then you can Run the Summarize Tool (you can run this by right clicking the Ward field in the Intersection output) and selecting Summarize (Ward is what you "Summarize" by). Then toggle open the plus sign on the Shape_Len field (or whatever field has the length calculated) and select "SUM" to get the length of road within each Ward.

If you need to Summarize each road by its name within each ward, you can still do that but you will need to first combine [Ward] with [RoadName] in a new field (e.g. WARD_ROADNM) and summarize based on the new field.

[image]

Comment: Forgot to thank you for your solution. Your solution had worked fantastic for this issue! Thanks!!

Comment: You are very welcome!